# Использование devtools chrome

Tags: вёрстка, visual-studio-code, google-chrome-devtools

Как сделать так, чтобы при изменении свойств css в дев тулз хром автоматически эти свойства изменялись и в редакторе vscode. Другими словами, редактировать исходные файлы непосредственно в Chrome. Любые сделанные изменения сохраняются в файловой системе и обновляются в редакторе

Answer (score 1):

Думаю такое невозможно реализовать

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Тут нужно немного кармы для комментариев